# How do I disable thinking-sphinx so that it doesn't affect heroku while I don't need to use it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Thinking sphinx is crashing my heroku app. I'd like to disable it and make it so it seems like I never added it to my app so that heroku can just ignore it. Is there a quick easy way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
heroku rollback
```

That will roll your heroku release version back to the previous one (presumably before you pushed up your `thinking-sphinx` changes.

If this does not roll back far enough, you can keep running the above command until it rolls back to a working version, or alternatively you can run `heroku releases` to get a list of releases and then call `heroku rollback vX` where `X` is the version you wish to roll back to.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#rollback for more info.